# Rails "No route matches" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting the following error in my Rails app:

No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"customers", :customer_id=>1}

Following is the jobs view line to link to edit customer details (customer has many jobs, but no nested resources):

```
<%= link_to job.customer_id, edit_customer_path(:customer_id => job.customer_id) %>
```

Following is edit definition in the controller:

```
def edit
  if params[:customer_id]
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])   
  elsif params[:id]
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # edit.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @customer }
  end
end
```

rake routes gives the following:

```
edit_customer GET    /customers/:id/edit(.:format) customers#edit
```

NOTE:

If I change the view to:

```
<%= link_to job.customer_id, edit_customer_path(:id => job.customer_id) %>
```

then I get the same error but with ":id=nil" (i.e. with no value passed at all):

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"customers", :id=>nil}
```

I am a little new to this, but can someone please explain what is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: in rails console try `app.edit_customer_path(1)`

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to pass a parameter, not a hardcoded value. Or have I misunderstood what you are saying?

Comment: Note that if I add edit_customer_path(1) in the view, it works, the edit page comes up. So something is wrong with the parameter being passed, but I can't figure out what...

Comment: ok then `edit_customer_path(job.try(:customer)) unless job.try(:customer).blank?` do it in your view hope it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Try writing your path like this

```
edit_customer_path(job.customer) if job.customer
```

---

In your routes, specify one parameter for customers.

```
resources :customers, param: :customer_id
```

so you always know what the id is going to look like. (there is some trickery required to make this work all the way through resources).

Also, another potential issue (which has caught me out a few times) is that I have instantiated on the same page a blank instance of the same class I am trying to route to. eg @customer = Customer.new, which the link to is looking for, but doesn't find an id as the record hasn't been saved.

I find named routes a hassle, and much prefer using polymorphic urls as they degrade gracefully.

In your case it would mean something like this.

```
link_to 'whev', [:edit, @customer]
```

Comment: Thanks, I amended the routes as per above, and changed my controller to remove references to :id, and now I get:

No route matches {:param=>:customer_id, :action=>"edit", :controller=>"customers", :customer_id=>1}

By the way I have no problem using :id. The only reason I changed this to :customer_id was to illustrate the issue. All I am trying to do is edit the customer details from the jobs page. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks, but if I do that I get 

No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"customers", :id=>nil}

Comment: i take it your looping through a list of jobs? I would imagine some of your jobs don't have customer id's

Comment: did that fix the problem?

Comment: yes thanks, i added a `% if job.customer_id %` clause in my view, and all good (though the customer should not be null - a different issue altogether ). thanks for your help!

Comment: i thought i did that already - i've done it again, let me know if it hasn't worked, i'm new on this site :)